# Mean Distance Between features on Two Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance

I am new to arcmap and need your help to resolve the below issue.
I have two feature layers about a town which was moved from one location to another. Now i need to calculate the mean distance between the new and old town.
I tried using Euclidean Distance but i understand the value returned are not correct. I also have a digital elevation model of the area.

Please refer the attached screenshot

[image: Two feature class with information of the same town after old and the new one after relocation]

Comment: How did you use Euclidean Distance, what is the returned value, and why is it incorrect?

Comment: Hi, I have two feature classes representing a small town. One feature class represents the old location of the town and the other feature class represents the new location of the same town. I have to add a new attribute to the new location feature class which describes the mean distance from the old location of the town in meters. Hope this helps

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any new information.  Comments are intended for potential answerers to request clarification - your response should be via edits to the question.